# PHP Comparing Two Dimensional Arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been racking my brain with this one.

I have two arrays:

Array 1 pulls from a CSV file.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => cgajate
            [date] => 20120918
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => badrock5
            [date] => 20120920
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => ricoetc
            [date] => 20120921
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => ricoetc1
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [uid] => darbyfired
            [date] => 20120922
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [uid] => sagers.andrew
            [date] => 20120922
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [uid] => frankfurt9
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [uid] => beachboys
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [uid] => panterafan
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [uid] => kingsxrules
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [uid] => richard.bitto
            [date] => 20120924
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [uid] => christopher.boss
            [date] => 20120925
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [uid] => eric.robinson2
            [date] => 20120926
        )

)
```

Array 2 pulls from the SQL database.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => cgajate
            [date] => 20120919
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => ricoetc
            [date] => 20120921
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => ricoetc1
            [date] => 20120922
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => frankfurt9
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [uid] => beachboys
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [uid] => panterafan
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [uid] => kingsxrules
            [date] => 20120923
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [uid] => eric.robinson2
            [date] => 20120926
        )

)
```

What I essentially what to do is check if there are any UID matches. If there are matches, it will check which date is more current than the other (so essentially what date is greater than). Then it will add them to an array with the data that UIDs didn't match from both arrays.

Sorry if it's hard to understand. It's slightly hard to explain.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Too many things, lol. I can't seem to merge the lasting data. I can output the UID matches and what dates I want to keep, but I can't seem to merge the data with the rest of the unique data.

Comment: One thing you might look into is underscore.php. Its simular to underscore.js, if you've ever heard of that. It provides a lot of "functional programming" features and can be super useful for comparing arrays.

Comment: To clarify. If array #1 consists of uids A and B, while array #2 consists of uids B and C, you want a final array that has A, C, and the later date for B?

Comment: Array 1 consists of a list of UIDs and dates as well as Array 2 consists of the same. I want to only output unique UIDs and the most current date for that UID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PHP arrays are themselves hash maps, you could iterate through one array and insert each date into a new array, keyed by UID:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($first_array as $x) {
    $out[$x['uid']] = $x['date'];
}
```

Then, you could iterate through the second array, checking if any of the UIDs already exist as keys in the `$out` array. If the UID already exists, then you can compare dates and take whichever piece of data you prefer. For example, something like:

```
foreach ($second_array as $y) {
    if (array_key_exists($y['uid'], $out)) {
        if ($out[$y['uid']] < $y['date']) {
            $out[$y['uid']] = $y['date'];
        }
    } else {
        $out[$y['uid']] = $date;
    }
}
```

Then, to flatten the data back down:

```
$_out = array();
foreach ($out as $uid => $date) {
    $_out[] = array("uid" => $uid, "date" => $date);
}
$out = $_out;
```

Comment: Each UID has it's own unique date. I don't think this would work, but thanks for the input.

Comment: If each UID has its own unique date, then this will merely deduplicate UIDs and take the later date from each duplicate, no? This should also merge the datasets - i.e.: all of the UIDs from both the first and second arrays will be keys in `$out`.

Comment: I will certainly try it and let you know.

Comment: This does not work. Now I get this.

    `Array
    (
        [cgajate] => 20120919
        [badrock5] => 
        [ricoetc] => 20120921
        [ricoetc1] => 20120922
        [darbyfired] => 
        [sagers.andrew] => 
        [frankfurt9] => 20120923
        [beachboys] => 20120923
        [panterafan] => 20120923
        [kingsxrules] => 20120923
        [richard.bitto] => 
        [christopher.boss] => 
        [eric.robinson2] => 20120926
    )`

Comment: If you need the data in the exact form as the original, you can then flatten it. I've updated the answer with some code that might do that for you.

Comment: Actually it looks like this works. I found only one thing wrong with your code but, this is excellent. `$out = array();
foreach ($first_array as $x) {
    $out[$x['uid']] = $x['date'];
}` Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy but it works.

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(
    array("uid" => "cgajate", "date" => 20120918),
    array("uid" => "badrock5", "date" => 20120920),
    array("uid" => "ricoetc", "date" => 20120921),
    array("uid" => "ricoetc1", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "darbyfired", "date" => 20120922),
    array("uid" => "sagers.andrew", "date" => 20120922),
    array("uid" => "frankfurt9", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "beachboys", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "panterafan", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "kingsxrules", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "richard.bitto", "date" => 20120924),
    array("uid" => "christopher.boss", "date" => 20120925),
    array("uid" => "eric.robinson2", "date" => 20120926));


$arr2 = Array(
    array("uid" => "cgajate", "date" => 20120919),
    array("uid" => "ricoetc", "date" => 20120921),
    array("uid" => "ricoetc1", "date" => 20120922),
    array("uid" => "frankfurt9", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "beachboys", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "panterafan", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "kingsxrules", "date" => 20120923),
    array("uid" => "eric.robinson2", "date" => 20120926));

function flatten ($arr) {
    $new_arr = array ();
    foreach ($arr as $sub_arr) {
        $new_arr[$sub_arr["uid"]] = $sub_arr["date"];
    } 
    return $new_arr;
}


$flat_arr1 = flatten ($arr1);
$flat_arr2 = flatten ($arr2);
$arr3 = array ();

foreach ($flat_arr1 as $key=>$value) {
    if (isset ($flat_arr2[$key])) {
        $value = $flat_arr1[$key] > $flat_arr2[$key] ? $flat_arr1[$key] : $flat_arr2[$key];
    }
    $arr3[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($flat_arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    if (isset ($flat_arr1[$key])) {
        $value = $flat_arr1[$key] > $flat_arr2[$key] ? $flat_arr1[$key] : $flat_arr2[$key];
    }
    $arr3[$key] = $value;
}

?> 

<pre><?php print_r($flat_arr1); ?></pre>

<pre><?php print_r($flat_arr2); ?></pre>

<pre><?php print_r($arr3); ?></pre>
```